# Spring boot: Serving public and private (restricted) static content

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-web` along with `embedded-jetty` and `starter-jersey` starter. The Jersey servlet context-path is configured in application.properties to serve from `/api`. So all `/api/.*` calls are handled over to Jersey.

Since I'm using `starter-web`, the static content is being served from `static/` directory as shown here:

[image]

All the resources listed under `static/public/` can be accessed without any restrictions. But the resources under `static/private` should be restricted and will be shown only if logged in.

To achieve this, I've written a filter:

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public static class PrivateContentFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        if (request.getRequestURI().matches(".*/static/private/.*")) {
            // Check for authentication in the cookie and procceed
            // The cookie is handed to an auth mirco-service, that does the actual validation. 
        }
    }
}
```

But this filter is only reached when the path is `api/.*` and not for the static content: `/public/.*` nor for `/private.*`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why don't you use Spring Security?

Comment: Seems like an overkill just to do something a simple filter can do, no? I don't use spring security in the project, so I'm looking for solutions without having to install additional libraries.

Comment: You will end up developing stuff that is already solved with Spring Security. Cookie handling, authentication etc

Comment: But you're assuming my spring application would be responsible for cookie management and authentications. Which is not the case. Like I said, I'm looking for a solution to avoid maintenance of additional libraries.

Comment: In your question I see:  // Check for authentication in the cookie and procceed

Comment: Ha, okay. I see the confusion. The check for authentication in the cookie is done by passing the cookie to a micro-service. I'll add that to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that is under /static is the context / so your filter regex must look like this:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    if (request.getRequestURI().matches("/private/.*")) {
        System.out.println("private");
    } else {
        System.out.println("public");
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}
```